# Change/Add parent class if child image source is empty

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class to a parent if the parent contains an image with a specific class and contains a `src` value using jQuery.

I do this by first removing all `img` tag's html that contain no `src` value. I then check if the class exists. I am assuming since i first remove the image tags with no image source then that should only leave image tags containing the class name left? (This is just my attempt feel free to provide a better solution)

My second function is currently not working as the goal I described above.

**JQUERY**

```js
$('.disc-image[src=""]').remove();
if ($('.si-innerWrap').hasClass('disc-image')) {
  $('.si-innerWrap').addClass('has-img');
}
```

```css
.si-innerWrap {
  border: 10px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.has-img {
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="si-innerWrap">
  <img class="disc-image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg">
</div>

<div class="si-innerWrap">
  <img class="disc-image" src="">
</div>

<div class="si-innerWrap">
  <img class="disc-image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg">
</div>

<div class="si-innerWrap">
  <img class="disc-image" src="">
</div>
```

Comment: Wow i made an error in my entry.. and u edited it incorrectly. And it refuses to let me edit it now. Thanks bud.

Comment: Try again now after reloading? What was the error?

Comment: I fixed it. Feel free to add your change now. Thanks

Comment: Na, it looks fine. `:)`

Comment: Ok cool. Sorry, when it said i couldnt correct myself and edit my post cuz u already edited i was like "Hands in the air" lol

Comment: Class selector selects an array of elements. So you can not say `$('.si-innerWrap').hasClass('disc-image')`

Comment: So what do i say instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `hasClass()` is incorrect, as the class you're looking for will be on the child `img` element, not the `.si-innerWrap` itself.

To fix this you can simply use `has()` to determine if the div container has any `.disc-image` elements remaninig in it after remove the `img` which had no `src` set on them, then add the class. Try this:

```js
$('.disc-image[src=""]').remove();
$('.si-innerWrap').has('.disc-image').addClass('has-img');
```

```css
.si-innerWrap {
  border: 10px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.has-img {
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="si-innerWrap">
  <img class="disc-image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg">
</div>

<div class="si-innerWrap">
  <img class="disc-image" src="">
</div>

<div class="si-innerWrap">
  <img class="disc-image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg">
</div>

<div class="si-innerWrap">
  <img class="disc-image" src="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great in your code example. For some reason i cant get it to work within my project files however. Not sure why. But thank you! Clearly you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

select child elements but add class to their parents:

```
   $('.disc-image[src=""]').remove();
   $('.disc-image').parent().addClass("has-img");
```

Note that `$('.si-innerWrap').addClass('has-img');` adds class to all elements of a class even if you put it inside if-then block.